# Custom Post Types cause 404 for pages?

Tags: 404-error

I have looked at the previous post here regarding a similar issue but what resolved them issues doesn't want to work for me.

Basically, I have a custom post type for football players for my home team, the slug for this post type is players and my permalink structure is /%category%/%postname%/
Now when I create a new player, and go to view the post, I get a 404, so I go to permalinks and click save. The custom post type of the player now works but with a strange issue, my pages now come back with a 404, post seem to work fine and aren't effected?

Now I am using a plugin called Easy Custom Content Types by Pippin, but this error also happend for me when using the Custom Post Type UI. I have tried different themes, deleting the .htaccess and nothing seems to work. The strange thing is that if I change the permalink structure back to default there is no issue, but I don't want that, I want to be able to use the permalink structure I'm currently using minus the errors.

So can anyone help to resolve this annoying error.

Thanks

Comment: First thing to test would be to try with permalinks at default, and secondary using one of the provided structures, ie. non-custom. It's highly likely the problem is a result of your chosen permalink structure..

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Disable permalinks, then re-enable them.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is probably the  /%category%/ in your permalink structure.

Comment: No its not that, I have tried with simply /%postname%/ and that causes the same error.

Comment: can you post your code for registering your post type?

Comment: Well I use a plugin but it has an export feature so you can import them into a fresh installation of Wordpress by adding this code to your functions.php file.

So here is the code:

http://pastebin.com/2PqMVd3d

It's just very frustrating, I have spent hours disabling plugins, changing themes, deleting the .htaccess file numerous times and everytime it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check for duplicate slugs/names.

If your post type has the same name (or slug or rewrite) as a category or page, it will wreak havoc with your permalinks and generate 404's. I just spent a day trying to figure this out on one of my own sites before I found the conflict.

Renaming the post type to something unique fixed it for me.

Comment: The slug name isn't the issue, as I only have 1 page and 1 post on my test site and there slugs are test and test2